# Pre-Moving user files prior to folder redirection to new folder

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, folder-redirection

I have folder redirection in place at the office I work for. The user files currently reside in a folder on my file server. I am in the process of reworking the GPO and AD structure to facilitate better organization of files and users.

My question/issue is, is there any way I can move my existing users files into their new home without having to wait the hour plus for windows to do it automatically. In a test environment, a user with about 2GB worth of redirected data took approx. 30 minutes to move at log in. I have users that have 10GB plus of data that I would like to move to it's new home prior to the user logging in and having to wait several hours. I've tried copying the files over manually, but windows still acts like it's transferring files at log in (during the 'Welcome' screen.)

Is there any way to do this that is tried and tested? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There is some discussion here that's worth looking at: http://serverfault.com/q/630905/7200

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a sort of work around for the time being. I am copying the redirected files over to the local drive of the computer while the user is still logged in. I then have them log off and back on to refresh the GPO and have them copy their files back to their Documents folder that is redirected to the new location. A bunch of copying, but it minimizes the amount of time on the Welcome screen.